# How do I get count of number of items in selection?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset, frequency

I want to list in array format how many in each Diet group (there are four) have Time > 21.

I have tried to solve this in RStudio.

```
data(ChickWeight)
newdata <- subset(ChickWeight, Time >= 21, select=Diet)
```

In order to find how many observations are in newdata, I used 
`nrow(newdata)`,
but I would like to find out how many observations meet the criteria just by making it a part of this expression:

```
newdata <- subset(ChickWeight, Time >= 21, select=Diet)
```

so that when I display `newdata` the table will also contain the number of observations that meet the criteria in a new column.

**Desire output:**

```
Diet   Number Observations
1      200 (I just created the numbers for this column as examples)
2       75
3      150
4      100
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: and the obs count would be a repeating number in a different column of `newdata`? What about `newdata$obs_count <- nrow(newdata)`?

Comment: I would like it displayed this way:
Diet   Number Observations
1           200 (what # is)
2           300 (what # is)
3             75 (what # is)
4             25 (what # is)

avid_useR: When I ran yours, I got NULL.

Comment: Please post your desired output in the question body itself

Comment: So basically you want to get the obs count for each `Diet` group?

Answer (score 5):

It can be done in `base`:

```r
transform(table(Diet=subset(ChickWeight, Time >= 21, select=Diet)))

#>   Diet Freq
#> 1    1   16
#> 2    2   10
#> 3    3   10
#> 4    4    9
```

Comment: M-M, thanks. It works. What is the purpose of "table"? Why is it needed?

Comment: @Metsfan You can read about it by running `?table()`. In short, table gives a cross tab with frequencies. I am just transforming it later to change the direction of output (run the code without `transform` to see). You should run `table` on couple more dataframes that you have to know what it does better.

Comment: When I ran it without transform I got this error: "Error in subset.data.frame(ChickWeight, select = Diet, weight) : 
  'subset' must be logical"

Comment: @Metsfan Are you assigning that to a column or something? For testing, just run that line without anything else before or after: ```table(Diet=subset(ChickWeight, Time >= 21, select=Diet))```

Comment: Okay, now it worked. I noticed that it converted the rows into columns. Interesting. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `summarize` from `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)

newdata %>%
  group_by(Diet) %>%
  summarize(Num_Obs = n())
```

We can even combine the `subset` to a single `dplyr` workflow:

```
ChickWeight %>%
  filter(Time >= 21) %>%
  group_by(Diet) %>%
  summarize(Num_Obs = n())
```

**Output:**

```
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Diet  Num_Obs
  <fct>   <int>
1 1          16
2 2          10
3 3          10
4 4           9
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a straightforward `aggregate` after the `subset` call:

```
newdata <- subset(ChickWeight, Time >= 21, select=Diet)

aggregate(cbind(Obs=Diet) ~ Diet, newdata, FUN=length)

#   Diet Obs
# 1    1  16
# 2    2  10
# 3    3  10
# 4    4   9
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a data table approach

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(ChickWeight)

df[Time >= 21, .(Number = .N), by = Diet]
#    Diet Number
# 1:    1     16
# 2:    2     10
# 3:    3     10
# 4:    4      9
```